# Set font size content UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I built an application to read mail on the `ipad`, when displayed html body content to `UIWebView` the font size it is not uniform, I can not adjust the font size as all the other applications `MailBox`, 'Gmail'..

I use:
`html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* Never autoresize text */
}`  
but does not solve the problem, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

try this one it worked for me

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wView {
    [wView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '50%'"];
    [wView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.zoom= '0.5'"];
}
```

Comment: may be this is not relevant answer of Question. your putting answer is for Zoom page Fit as par screen.

Comment: i soleved problem, using CSS.

Comment: it is not working on iOS 10.1.1 is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can set font size of webview , like

```
NSString *fontsize;  
fontsize=20px;


NSString *WebviewString;  
WebviewString=@"xyz";
```

Put the value of fontsize and WebviewString in this:

```
 [MywebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='text-align:justify; font-size:%@;font-family:Helvetica;color:#ffff;'>%@",fontsize,WebviewString] baseURL:nil];
```

Hope it will helpyou.